# combine N_m3u8DL-RE & SubtitleEdit mkvmerge using CMD

Tags: command-line, audio, video, mp3

How do I combine N_m3u8DL-RE with SubtitleEdit using CMD
I want to Download a video file with N_m3u8DL-RE, but before merging, I want to use the

```
SubtitleEdit /convert video.nl.srt srt /ReverseRtlStartEnd
```

command to correct the subtitle direction.
How can I do this?
Knowing that the output is sometimes several audio files or subtitles in different languages, but there is a language identifier
video.mp4 Video.en.mp3  video.nl.mp3 video.en.srt video .nl.srt
And when i will merging it, how can I make mkvmerge automatically recognize the language from identifier
normaly i use

```
mkvmerge.exe --ui-language en --output "video.mkv" --language 0:en "(" "video.mp4" ")" --language 0:nl "(" "video.nl.mp3" ")" --language 0:nl "(" "video.nl.srt" ")"
```